# Отложенная загрузка картинок для pagespeed

Tags: html, img, lazyloading, pagespeed

`pagespeed.web.dev` пишет сделать картинку отложенной закрузкой, я ее сделал, но он все равно пишет сделать ее отложенной.

Использовал библиотеку https://github.com/verlok/vanilla-lazyload

Когда картинка в поле видимости все работает корректно, из data-src создается атрибут src и картинка отображается

```
<img class="lazy" data-src="img/s1.jpg" alt="">
```

Подскажите что он тупит, что ему еще не нравится?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если ленивая загрузка и вправду работает, то, кажется, без конкретного примера будет сложно разбираться. Если пытаться угадывать от балды — может, эти две картинки слишком близко к видимому краю экрана и параметр threshold, по умолчанию равный 300 пикселей, вынуждает их загружаться?

Comment: @andreymal они примерно в середине страницы, где то на 1000px прокрутить вниз. Вообще странно как то этот pagespeed работает, один раз как то не показало на картинки, теперь показывает, потом как то еще раз не показало, теперь снова показывает. Уже не знаю что делать.

Comment: Продолжаю рассуждать от балды: а вообще, может, не тащить никаких сторонних библиотек и просто добавить атрибут [loading="lazy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-loading)?